Anylogic: Issue with labeling the agent and then separating them
Can anybody help me with the error message?
The two left-most pictures show the agent arrival schedule and a code for agent arrival.
Right next to it, two back-to-back pictures show Erros. Can you please help me with the errors in the code?
I am trying to label and then separate agents based on the label assigned to them?

re your 3rd error:
case is a special Java keyword, hence it is in purple (google the switch statement syntax).
use agent instead and learn about the magic lightbulb to use local keywords correcty.
1st and 2nd errors: Your Case agent type has no public getLabel() method. Either create it or make it public.
And use code-complete ALWAYS. That way, you never try to access something that is not reachable.

I would really appreciate it if you could help me understanding how to create a method within the agent "Case" type.

Pls avoid asking "how to" questions on SOF, it is a pure Q&A place. For "how to", best use LinkedIn, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community . And pls upvote if a reply was helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote
